# Failure to run db:migrate in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run db:migrate after installing image attachment via paperclip gem and it won't allow me to do migration. Could someone help please? Thanks a lot [This is what it said on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LfIW.png)

This is my config file [config/database.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45pdQ.png)

This is my create item table:

```
class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :todo_items do |t|
      t.column :content
      t.column :deadline

      t.references :todo_list, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Item model

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :todo_list

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500>", thumb: "100x100#"}

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  def completed?

    !completed_at.blank?

  end

end
```

Comment: Please post your config/database.yml file

Comment: default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Comment: @jaysoifer: default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3


test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Comment: @VuXuanMinh yo have to edit your question an add there the config file and any information

Comment: you have to (better, few people open images) put your code in normal text

Comment: Show your migrations...Is there a table called `items`table in the first place?

Comment: @inye: sorry I just wanted to show the full code. Anyway yes there is an items table. I edited my post so it's there.

Comment: @uDaY: Yes there is an items table. I put it in my post.

Comment: can you show your ToDoItems model?

Comment: @VuXuanMinh can you post the first lines of error terminal?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it worked.

Comment: yeah actually the first line says no such table :(

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: items: ALTER TABLE "items" ADD "image_file_name" varchar

Comment: @uDaY: yup I showed my Item model. Think sth wrong with it but can't figure out why :(

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a column to database that doesn't exist. You don't happen to have `items` table you have `todo_items` table your migration should look something like:

`$ bin/rails generate migration AddAttachmentImageToTodoItems attachment_image:string`